# SetLayeredWindowAttributes requires Admin priviledges?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm running a program that makes some ALPHA effects on labels, fonts, images using the Windows´ SetLayeredWindowAttributes function. It´s functioning prefectly within Visual Studio 2013, running without Administrator priviledge.

I run in DEBUG and RELEASE mode from VS2013 and I know the ADMIN is not set because I call VS normally and I execute some "drag-and-drop" operations (which require a NORMAL priviledge instead ADMIN).

But, if I compile and run the program within its normal folder (C:\ProgramFiles\etc) in the SAME computer, the function does not appear to be executing - all labels, images and so forth appear suddenly.

So, is this function an ADMIN-PRIVILEDGE required?

The code for testing is:

```
Private Const GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20)
Private Const WS_EX_LAYERED = &H80000
Private Const LWA_ALPHA = &H2

Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" _
  Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Integer, _
  ByVal nIndex As Integer) As Integer

Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" _
   Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Integer, _
   ByVal nIndex As Integer, ByVal dwNewLong As Integer) _
   As Integer

Private Declare Function SetLayeredWindowAttributes Lib _
    "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Integer, ByVal crKey As Integer, _
    ByVal bAlpha As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Integer) As Integer



Public Function TransForm(ByVal fhWnd As Long, ByVal Alpha As Byte) As Boolean
    'Set alpha between 0-255
    ' 0 = Invisible , 128 = 50% transparent , 255 = Opaque

    SetWindowLong(fhWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_LAYERED)
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(fhWnd, 0, Alpha, LWA_ALPHA)
    LastAlpha = Alpha
    TransForm = True


End Function


------ CODE -----

TransForm(lblBottomLeft.Handle.ToInt32, CByte(i))
TransForm(lblBottomRight.Handle.ToInt32, CByte(i))

For i = 255 To 0 Step -5
    TransForm(Me.Handle.ToInt32, CByte(i))
    sleep(10)
Next
TransForm(Me.Handle.ToInt32, 0)
```

Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE:**
Just the labels are not fading, although they fade within VS2013. Since labels have no OPACITY property, it´s clear they won´t fade - at least in the very first moment. But using that API they **fade like the form**, but ONLY within the VS2013.

Comment: Hard to guess what "appear suddenly" could possibly mean.  Program for a while with Option Strict On at the top of your source files.  And keep in mind that this is only supported on a Form, not a child control like a Label, unless you run Win8 or higher.  And use the Opacity property instead.

Comment: Thanks Hans, but let me be more clear:  1- some controls has no opacity (like LABELS);   2- it is functioning 100% inside VS (labels appear in smooth mode) but not after put within the PROGRAMFILES folder;  3) Appear Suddenly is without the fade effect I already have in VS2013 running in both DEBUG and RELEASE mode.  Thanks!